# Exception Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor while parsing DateTime using LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

Getting Exception while parsing the DateTime. Is something i am missing here

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("0DDDHHmmss");
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("0DDDHHmmss");
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("0365231109", formatter).withYear(2016);
```

Following is the exception i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '0365231109' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfYear=365},ISO resolved to 23:11:09 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at AutocomFDParser.main(AutocomFDParser.java:204)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfYear=365},ISO resolved to 23:11:09 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:461)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfYear=365},ISO resolved to 23:11:09 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalDate.from(LocalDate.java:368)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:456)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't specify a year in the input String that you want to convert to a LocalDateTime.

A `LocalDateTime` has to be necessarily be associated to a year.

So the following exception is thrown :

> Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfYear=365},ISO
>   resolved to 23:11:09 of type java.time.format.Parsed

You could set a fake date as input as you overwrite it with : `withYear(2016)` :

```
String stringInput = "02000365231109";
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("0yyyyDDDHHmmss");
LocalDateTime date2 = LocalDateTime.parse(stringInput, formatter2).withYear(2016);
```

If you cannot modify directly the input you could create a new String with the correct format before invoking the `parse()` method :

```
String stringInput = "0365231109";
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("0yyyyDDDHHmmss");
stringInput = "02000" + stringInput.substring(1);
LocalDateTime date2 = LocalDateTime.parse(stringInput, formatter2).withYear(2016);
```

Comment: You are welcome. It could be indeed a little more specific.

Comment: hi, sir. first up-vote. use your approach will be failed when `dayOfYears > 366`. and the OP date pattern is more like a `Duration` not a `*DateTime`.

Comment: @holi-java I agree that using a Duration instance and your answer is fine according to the way you are interpreting the op question but it doesn't make part clearly of the op requirement.

Answer (score 2):

**FIRST** your date time pattern is more like a [Duration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) rather than a [LocalDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). you can using [TemporalAccessor#query](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html#query-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery-) to creates a [Duration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) from a [TemporalAccessor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html). for example:

```
List<TemporalField> fields = Arrays.asList(DAY_OF_YEAR, HOUR_OF_DAY
        , MINUTE_OF_HOUR, SECOND_OF_MINUTE);

Duration duration = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("0DDDHHmmss").parse("0366231109")
    .query(temporal -> fields.stream().reduce(
            Duration.ZERO,
            (it, field) -> it.plus(field.getFrom(temporal), field.getBaseUnit()),
            Duration::plus
    ));
```

**THEN** you can create a [LocalDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) base on the [Duration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) instance. for example:

```
LocalDateTime start=LocalDateTime.of(Year.of(2016).atDay(1),LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0));
LocalDateTime result = start.plus(duration);

System.out.println(result);
```

### Output

> "2017-01-01T23:11:09"